# Android chart with variable line stroke width

Tags: java, android, charts, mpandroidchart

I am trying to create Android App with [chart with variable line stroke width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLjWH.png)  like this one in the link.
I have tried to realize it with [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). Override **drawCubicBezier** method in **LineChartRenderer** class and to set dynamically setStrokeWidth on Paint. But nothing happens. Probably my knowledge is not enough to do it.
Can you help me how to achieve a different line thickness or if there is another chart library that has such functionality?

This is how I set my new Renderer

```
chart2.setRenderer(new myLineChartRenderer(chart2, chart2.getAnimator(), chart2.getViewPortHandler()));
```

This is the class

```
 public class myLineChartRenderer extends LineChartRenderer {


    public myLineChartRenderer(LineChart chart, ChartAnimator animator, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        super(chart, animator, viewPortHandler);

    }

    @Override
    protected void drawCubicBezier(ILineDataSet dataSet) {
        Path mPath = new Path();
        ArrayList<Path> mPaths = new ArrayList<Path>();


        mRenderPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mRenderPaint.setDither(true);
        mRenderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mRenderPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mRenderPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        //mRenderPaint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);

        float phaseY = mAnimator.getPhaseY();

        Transformer trans = mChart.getTransformer(dataSet.getAxisDependency());

        mXBounds.set(mChart, dataSet);

        float intensity = dataSet.getCubicIntensity();

        cubicPath.reset();

        if (mXBounds.range >= 1) {

            float prevDx = 0f;
            float prevDy = 0f;
            float curDx = 0f;
            float curDy = 0f;

            // Take an extra point from the left, and an extra from the right.
            // That's because we need 4 points for a cubic bezier (cubic=4), otherwise we get lines moving and doing weird stuff on the edges of the chart.
            // So in the starting `prev` and `cur`, go -2, -1
            // And in the `lastIndex`, add +1

            final int firstIndex = mXBounds.min + 1;
            final int lastIndex = mXBounds.min + mXBounds.range;

            Entry prevPrev;
            Entry prev = dataSet.getEntryForIndex(Math.max(firstIndex - 2, 0));
            Entry cur = dataSet.getEntryForIndex(Math.max(firstIndex - 1, 0));
            Entry next = cur;
            int nextIndex = -1;

            if (cur == null) return;

            // let the spline start
            cubicPath.moveTo(cur.getX(), cur.getY() * phaseY);
            mPath.moveTo(cur.getX(), cur.getY() * phaseY);

            for (int j = mXBounds.min + 1; j <= mXBounds.range + mXBounds.min; j++) {

                prevPrev = prev;
                prev = cur;
                cur = nextIndex == j ? next : dataSet.getEntryForIndex(j);

                nextIndex = j + 1 < dataSet.getEntryCount() ? j + 1 : j;
                next = dataSet.getEntryForIndex(nextIndex);

                prevDx = (cur.getX() - prevPrev.getX()) * intensity;
                prevDy = (cur.getY() - prevPrev.getY()) * intensity;
                curDx = (next.getX() - prev.getX()) * intensity;
                curDy = (next.getY() - prev.getY()) * intensity;

                cubicPath.cubicTo(prev.getX() + prevDx, (prev.getY() + prevDy) * phaseY,
                        cur.getX() - curDx,
                        (cur.getY() - curDy) * phaseY, cur.getX(), cur.getY() * phaseY);
                mPath.cubicTo(prev.getX() + prevDx, (prev.getY() + prevDy) * phaseY,
                        cur.getX() - curDx,
                        (cur.getY() - curDy) * phaseY, cur.getX(), cur.getY() * phaseY);
                mPaths.add(mPath);
               // Log.i("Curve", (prev.getX() + prevDx)+" | "+ ((prev.getY() + prevDy) * phaseY)+" | "+ (cur.getX() - curDx)+" | "+ ((cur.getY() - curDy) * phaseY)+" | "+ cur.getX()+" | "+ (cur.getY() * phaseY));
            }
        }

        // if filled is enabled, close the path
        if (dataSet.isDrawFilledEnabled()) {

            cubicFillPath.reset();
            cubicFillPath.addPath(cubicPath);

            //drawCubicFill(mBitmapCanvas, dataSet, cubicFillPath, trans, mXBounds);
        }

        mRenderPaint.setColor(dataSet.getColor());

        mRenderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        trans.pathValueToPixel(cubicPath);

        //mBitmapCanvas.drawPath(cubicPath, mRenderPaint);
        for(int i=0; i<mPaths.size();i++)
        {
            mRenderPaint.setStrokeWidth(i+30);
            mBitmapCanvas.drawPath(mPaths.get(i), mRenderPaint);
        }

        mRenderPaint.setPathEffect(null);
    }
}
```

I tried to divide the path into separate parts and change the thickness of the line while drawing them, but the result is totally wrong.

Comment: Can I see your code inside drawCubicBezier() method which you have override, please ?

Comment: I made changes to my question and now you can see the code

Comment: I am able to change  line stroke width. Are you using LineChat.java from the library or you created your own ?

Comment: You want updated thickness remains same from start to end or something else ? I mean by default thickness is 2 and I changes it to 20, then line stroke remains 20 from start to end. Is it your requirement ? Or you want few line stroke width 5, some are 10, some are 2 then some are 15 like wise ?

Comment: I can also change the line width ... but on the whole line. Can you see this screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLjWH.png
This is what I am trying to do.
The line is thinner at the end.